# OrientDB: Check against LET Variable in WHERE Clause

Tags: where-clause, orientdb, let

I am trying to write an OrientDB batch script to

1. extract a DateTime from a specific record (T1)
2. increase the DateTime by a certain amount (T2)
3. search for records that have a DateTime between T1 and T2

   BEGIN
   LET T1 = SELECT time AS value FROM MyClass WHERE id = someID
   LET T2 = SELECT sum(first($T1.value).asLong(), someTime).asDateTime() as value
   SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE time > $T1 AND time < $T2
   COMMIT

This works fine as long as I don't use $T1 and $T2 (or $T1.value, $T2.value) in the WHERE clause, but strings like "2018-01-01 00:00:00". To better understand the difference between "2018-01-01 00:00:00" and $T1/$T2 (or $T1.value/$T2.value) I added a RETURN $T1/$T2 (or $T1.value/$T2.value) in the end and received the exact same string via studio.

So why can I use a hand-written string in WHERE clause, but not the value of some custom variable?

How would I have to rewrite my script to work as intended?

Comment: Hi @larsman, which version of OrientDB you use to write the script?

Comment: @ldacrema I'm using version 2.2.34.

Comment: Hi, in the second let there is a missing FROM, can you post an example with some values, even fake? Thx